# sendResourceAtURL multipeer IOS7

Tags: ios

I have an image and I need to send it via bluetooth to another device. The data is this:

```
NSData *Recording = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ext", button.titleLabel.text];
myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    [myDictionary setObject:str forKey:@"fileName"];
                    [myDictionary setObject:@"Recording" forKey:@"fileType"];
                    [myDictionary setObject:Recording forKey:@"FileData"];


NSData* myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDictionary];
```

I need to send either myData or myDictionary using the following method:

```
progress = [session sendResourceAtURL:anUrl withName:[imageUrl lastPathComponent] toPeer:peerID withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        // Implement this block to know when the sending resource transfer completes and if there is an error.
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Send resource to peer [%@] completed with Error [%@]", peerID.displayName, error);
        }
        else {
            // Create an image transcript for this received image resource

        }
    }];
```

As you can see I have to send a resource at url, and the receiver will receive the resource "at url" and I have to get an NSMutabledictionary from that url. Basically I have to send this myDictionary but I am having trouble with figuring out how the url thing works. Can anybody explain me what url I have to use and how to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood what you want but it looks like you simply are stuck at the transfer point.

Since you have already converted everything to an NSData object, on the sender side you need to call something like this:

```
// Assume peerID is correct and data has been prepared
NSError *error;
if ( ![session sendData:data
                toPeers:@[peerID]
               withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable
                  error:&error] )
    NSLog(@"ERROR - Unable to queue message for delivery - %@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

While on the receiver side, whoever is the MCSessionDelegate will get called via:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session
        didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
              fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID;
```

Where you will likely "unarchive" the NSData object to do something with it.

Let me also add an observation...

From your example it looks like you are stuffing the whole content of a file into the dictionary you are then archiving and sending. That's probably doable but not advisable.

A better approach would be to send the file as a separate resource. For example look at this sample for the sender:

```
// Assume peerID and filePath are both valid and correct 
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
NSString *fileName = [fileURL lastPathComponent];
NSError *error;
[session sendResourceAtURL:resourceURL
                  withName:fileName
                    toPeer:peerID
     withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
         if (error)
             NSLog(@"Sending to [%@] failed: %@",peerID.displayName, error);
     }];
```

The receiver's MCSessionDelegate would then receive both this at transfer start:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session 
        didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName
                                 fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
                             withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress;
```

...and this when the transfer ends:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session 
        didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName
                                  fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
                                     atURL:(NSURL *)temporaryURL
                                 withError:(NSError *)error;
```